# How to locate the source of a crash in Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I fix a lot of problems by using the LogCat in Android. Then also on certain crashes I have the Logcat and/or Console to tell me the source of the crash. It tells me the exact line in my code where the crash took place.

However I get a LOT of crashes that don't show anything on the LogCat. In the "Debug" window it simply shows me the stack trace which doesn't give me any helpful information (see screenshot).

How can I solve the crashes during the times when I only get the stack trace?

[image]

Comment: you can double click the line on the logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace shown in debug mode is pretty much the same you see in logcat, the only difference is that, it will stop in each propagation of the exception, in order to move to the next step in Debug Perspective on the top bar you can click on "resume" button, it will take you to the next step so you can continue tracking it down, if you keep clicking on resume there's a big chance that you will see the stacktrace in logcat as you are used to..

Regards!

Comment: That works! Why does it sometimes print the crash to the logcat immediately while other times I have to click "Resume"?

Comment: Seems like some runtime exceptions have some sort of breakpoint mechanism when in debug mode for some specific threads, i don't know exactly what threads have the mechanism but there's always a way to trackdown an exception either by debuging it or just printing it. If the answer solved your problem would be nice of you accept it, so in future people take time to answer your questions...